# Динамическое выделение памяти через умные указатели

Tags: c++, указатели, vector, smart-pointer, heap

Нужно выделить 120 объектов динамически,а потом хранить вектор указателей на них
У кого-то есть идеи, как сделать лучше,чем сейчас(п.с. код не работает в цикле)?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Customer*> customerList(120,nullptr);

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Customer>> customers(new std::vector<Customer>(120));

    for (auto i = 0;i<customers->size();i++)
    {
        customerList.push_back(&(customers->[i]));
    }

    //cout << customers->at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а где вы взяли такое выражение   &(customers->[i] ????

Comment: У вас customerList хранит Customer, а вы в него пытаетесь запихнуть shared_ptr с вектором Customer ?

Comment: хотел взять адрес итого элемента вектора через указатель @ARHovsepyan

Comment: @Fqqlt нет,там Customer*

Comment: @HideME Ну вот, там Customer*, а вы в него хотите положить shared_ptr с вектором Customer-ов

Comment: Честно, я ничего не понел, что вы в итоге хотите делать.  Непонятна формулировка вопроса, но вы одному типу  присваивать пытаетесь совершенно другой

Comment: @Fqqlt не подскажите,как исправить?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan нужно выделить 120 объектов динамически,а потом хранить вектор указателей на них

Comment: @HideME Создайте вектор shared_ptr-ов, и в цикле проинициализируйте каждый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или `customerList` должен содержать  умные указатели:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Customer> >
customerList(120, std::make_shared<Customer>());
```

или  умный указатель вообше не нужен:

```
std::vector<Customer*> customerList(120);      
for (int i = 0; i < 120;i++)
{
    customerList[i] = new Customer;
}
```

а вот так, как вы написали в комментариях, у вас будет 240 элементов, из которых 120 неинициализированы, поскольку вы должны инициализировать элементы вектора, а не добавлять в конец новые

Comment: я выбрал умные,чтобы память освободилась сама

Comment: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Customer>> vec(120, nullptr);

 for (auto i : vec)
 {
  vec.push_back(std::make_shared<Customer>(new Customer));
 }`

тоже вроде работает(как оказалось - нет)

Comment: Другое дело, но лучше сразу инициализировать  вектор   120 тью такими элементами

Comment: вы написали и сразу удалили это способ @AR Hovsepyan

Comment: я подумал о вам не нужен

Comment: нужно любое мнение @AR Hovsepyan

Comment: `std::make_shared<Customer>(new Customer)` можно сократить до `std::make_shared<Customer>()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Customer>> vec(120, nullptr);

for (auto& i : vec)
{
    i = std::shared_ptr<Customer>(new Customer);
}
```